# combinatorial analysis (choir)

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

A school teacher has 6 girls and 8 boys to arrange for a choir. Determine the number of ways she can arrange the 14 children,

a) if the boys should stand behind the girls.

b) in a single row, if the girls must be kept together.

c) in a single row, if no two girls should stand next to each other.

**My solution**

a) $^8P_8.^6P_6$

b) $9!(6!)$

c) $\dfrac{14!}{3!8!}$ (this not quite sure!!)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

Your answers to the first two problems are correct.

> A school teacher has $6$ girls and $8$ boys to arrange for a choir.  Determine the number of ways she can arrange the $14$ children in a single row if no two girls should stand next to each other.

The teacher can arrange the boys in a row in $8!$ ways.  This creates nine spaces in which the teacher can place the girls, seven between adjacent boys and two at the ends of the row.
$$\square b \square b \square b \square b \square b \square b \square b \square b \square$$
To ensure that no two of the girls are adjacent, the teacher must choose six of these nine spaces for the girls.  The girls can then be placed in the selected spaces in $6!$ ways.
$$8!\binom{9}{6}6!$$